# Парсинг сайта с помощью xpath. Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, requests

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно вытащить ссылки на разделы [этого](http://worldagnetwork.com/) сайта.

```
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-28"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/community/">Community</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/crops/">Crops</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-27"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/livestock/">Livestock</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/technology/">Technology</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/business/">Business</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-29"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/policy/">Policy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-53"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/environment/">Environment</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-82"><a href="http://worldagnetwork.com/category/rd/">R&#038;D</a></li>
```

Не совсем понимаю, как пользоваться xpath.

Вот что делаю я:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import lxml.html as LH

url = 'http://worldagnetwork.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = LH.document_fromstring(result.content)
print(tree.xpath('//div/ul/li')[0].get('href'))
```

`print(tree.xpath('//div/ul'))` уже выводит пустой список.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного недописали селектор

`'//div/ul/li'` - выберет все `li`  родителем которых является `ul`, родителем которых является какой-нибуть `div`.

Т.к. вам нужны не `li`  а `a` которые лежат внутри `li` нужно просто добавить `a` в конец селектора

`//div/ul/li/a`

```
links = tree.xpath("//div/ul/li/a")

for l in links:
    print( l.get( 'href' ) )
```

Это выедет все ссылки которые вам нужны.

Если вы хотите получить адреса, которые перечисленны в верхнем меню (полагаю что приедённый кусок html оттуда, то лучше использовать более специализированный селектор). `//div/ul/li/a` выведет несколько лишних ссылок. Для того чтобы получить ссылки из меню лучше использовать такой селектор

```
//div[contains(@class, "nav-collapse")]/ul/li[contains(@class, "menu-item")]/a[@href]
```

Выберет все `a` у которых есть `href`, прямым родителем которых является `li` с классом `menu-item`, которые находятся в `div` с классом `nav-collapse`.

Comment: Я меня tree.xpath('//div/ul') уже возвращает пустой список(

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что `tree.xpath('//div/ul/')[0].get('href')`  был пустым или без `[0].get('href')`? Если второе то, скорее всего, не удаётся получить данные с сайта (`request.content` сожержит что-то не то).

Comment: Разобрался с `tree.xpath('//div/ul')` и `tree.xpath('//div/ul/li/a')` возвращает действительно то, что нужно. А вот `tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "nav-collapse")]/li[contains(@class, "menu-item")]/a[@href]')` возвращает пустой список.

Comment: Тут тоже разобрался. Нужно было дописать `/ul`. Спасибо вам:)

Comment: Незачто. Поправил второй селектор в ответе, вдруг ещё когда пригодится.